# Passing Attributes to Child View in Compound Views

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-custom-view

I'm trying to make a compound view, whereby I can set attributes in XML and have them be passed to the children in the compound view. In the code below, I want to set the `android:text` and have it passed to the `EditText`.

Is this possible without having to set every attribute as a custom attribute?

**Activity.xml:**

```
<FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <com.app.CustomLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="child_view_text" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**custom_view.xml:**

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</merge>
```

**CustomView.java:**

```
public ValidationTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    View v = inflate(context, R.layout.custom_view, this);

    mEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mTextInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of having the EditText inside CustomLayout.xml you can instantiate it in CustomView.java passing the AttributeSet:

```
public class ValidationTextInputLayout extends LinearLayout
{
    public ValidationTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        View v = inflate(context, R.layout.custom_view, this);

        mTextInputLayout = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout);

        mEditText = new EditText(context, attrs);
        mTextInputLayout.AddView(mEditText);
    }

    /* Properties etc... */
}
```

For anyone still having this issue.

Comment: What language is this written in?

Comment: I wrote it in java but I myself use c# and Xamarin so haven't had time to check it compiles. I've edited my example to fix a syntax error.

Comment: Nice, simple solution! As a heads up for anyone using this: it does work, but be careful about unintended consequences of passing the whole `AttributeSet` to the child. In my case, the `AttributeSet` included `android:id`, which meant both parent and child had the same id; to work around this, I explicitly invoked `setId()` on the child after creating it in the `init` method. This worked for my purposes, but I imagine there could be other attributes that might break things when passed through in this way. A bit hacky, but overall still preferable in my mind to using custom attributes

Answer (score 0):

I think probably you can put the custom text (i.e., child_view_text) in a theme, then use the theme on the parent layout or view. With doing that, all child views will have the attribute android:text passed in with the custom text.

In your case, it might look like:

```
<string name="child_view_text">Child View Text</string>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:text">@string/child_view_text</item>
</style>

<FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"/>
     <com.app.CustomLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. In some cases I need to pass different custom attributes, i.e. "app:box_checked=true".

Answer (score 0):

**com.app.CustomLayout** extends a Layout, meaning it can't take android:text as an attribute.  You'll need to create a custom attribute for your CustomLayout class and in said CustomLayout class, inflate your custom_view (as you're doing above), parse the attrs for your custom text string, then call mEditText.setText(customLayoutText).